# Power of Hyperedge Replacement Grammars (HRGs)

Tags: graph-theory, graph-algorithms, fl.formal-languages, grammars

Can HRGs generate languages which equal or include the following graph languages:

1. All (bipartite) graphs of bounded degree
2. All (bipartite) planar graphs of bounded degree
3. All (bipartite) planar graphs in a square grid (so that every vertex has 4 neighbors)
4. A good language of expander graphs

The HRGs can potentially generate additional graphs outside of those languages or generate predictable additional vertices and edges that can be removed through post-processing. It would also be of interest whether node replacement (C-edNCE specifically) languages can generate these languages.